# Gadget does not export plot

Tags: r, shiny

I've created a miniUI app inside RStudio which makes plots what the user can export some kind of format like pdf or png. Unfortunately it seems to be a problem with the export function when I use Shiny Gadget.

Is there a known solution which solves it?

Here is a small example:

```
library(shiny)
library(miniUI)

ui <- miniPage(
    gadgetTitleBar("Sample Gadget"),
    miniContentPanel(
      plotOutput("testPlot", height = "100%"),
      downloadButton('downloadPlot', 'download button')
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    plotInput <-  function(){
        plot(mtcars)
    }

    output$testPlot  <- renderPlot({
        print(plotInput())
    })

    output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() { paste("export", '.png', sep='') },
            content = function(file) {
                png(file,
                    bg="white",
                    type="cairo",
                    units="in", 
                    width=10, 
                    height=8, 
                    pointsize=12, 
                    res=180)
                par(mar=c(0,0,0,0), xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
                print(plotInput())
                dev.off()
    })
}

runGadget(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

I noticed when I run the app in an external mode with this:

```
runGadget(shinyApp(ui, server), viewer = browserViewer())
```

It works fine, but I prefer to use in a dialog mode.

Comment: Works fine on Win7 / RStudio 1.0.136 / R 3..3.2 / Shiny 1.0.0 / miniUI 0.1.1

Comment: Good to hear. My system: Win10 / R version 3.3.2 (MRO) / Rstudio Version 1.0.136 / shiny_0.14.1 / miniUI_0.1.1. Maybe it is a Win10 bug.

Comment: Edit: I also tried it with Win8 and found the same issue

Comment: It also worked fine for me: Win10 / RStudio Version 1.0.136  / R 3.3.2 / Shiny 1.0.0 / miniUI 0.1.1. So maybe updating your Shiny version may fix it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the issue:

There could be a problem with Microsoft R Open (3.3.2). When try to install the latest shiny package from MRAN It only installs 'shiny_0.14.1.zip'

I tried it with R 3.3.2 and everything looks fine.

MRO 3.3.2:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/tarkomatas/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2016-11-01/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/shiny_0.14.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2649191 bytes (2.5 MB)
downloaded 2.5 MB
```

R 3.3.2:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/tarkomatas/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/shiny_1.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2745865 bytes (2.6 MB)
downloaded 2.6 MB
```

Strange issue...